# Where can I read the Ishvaragitabhashya of Vijnanabhiksu online in English?

Tags: translation-request, resource

I would like to read the ***Ishvaragitabhashya***, [Vijnanabhiksu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijnanabhiksu)'s commentary on the ***[Ishvara Gita](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishvara_Gita)*** online, in English. Can anyone provide me the relevant link or PDF for it?

The interesting thing about this commentary is that its the only commentary written by a Vaishnava on the ***[Ishvara Gita](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishvara_Gita)*** since Vaishnavas usually reject Ishvara Gita (as it downplays the importance of the ***Bhagavad Gita*** and shows Shiva as the supreme God instead of Shree Krishna).

Comment: By God's grace i got a book — [Īśvara-gītā , its Philosophy as expounded by Vijñāna
Bhikṣu](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/a-history-of-indian-philosophy-volume-3/d/doc209993.html)